# Accented characters cause the end of $_COOKIE string on IPhone in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, string, non-ascii-characters

When i read a string that contains characters like è,ò,à ecc.. from cookies in php, on iphone the character cause the end of the string while on android there's no problem, it works perfectly.

### Example

string in cookie: "1 caffè al bar"
string printed in php from iphone:

```
echo $_COOKIE["stringa"]; # outputs "1 caff"
```

How could i resolve it?

Comment: Use [base64_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode).

Comment: Thank u very much, it works!

Comment: HTTP headers _must_ be composed of 7-bit-safe characters, so anything non-ASCII needs to be encoded somehow.